# BIM model into Scene

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

Does anyone know how to convert an `.ifc` file into a Scene using SceneKit? I have tried with [AssetImportKit](https://github.com/eugenebokhan/AssetImportKit) but had no luck using the following code:

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import AssetImportKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var sceneView: SCNView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        do {
          let assimpScene = try SCNScene.assimpScene(filePath: "AC20-Institute-Var-2.ifc",
                                                      postProcessSteps: [.defaultQuality])
          let modelScene = assimpScene.modelScene
          modelScene.rootNode.childNodes.forEach {
            sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode($0)
          }
        } catch {
          debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

but get the error:

```
" Scene importing failed for filePath AC20-Institute-Var-2.ifc"
" Scene importing failed with error "
""
```

I feel there could be a better way to do this instead by converting the `.ifc` file into a `.dae/.obj/.usdz` file then load that as a scene without the need for AssetImportKit.

Any help or insight would be great thanks

Answer (score 0):

Same error for me but I implement **AssimpKit** and in **ViewDidLoad** you should write;

```
let scene=try SCNAssimpScene.assimpScene(with: URL(string: filePath), postProcessFlags: AssimpKitPostProcessSteps(rawValue: AssimpKitPostProcessSteps.process_FlipUVs.rawValue | AssimpKitPostProcessSteps.process_Triangulate.rawValue), error: ())
```

Also you can read ifc file from name if you have it download in xcode.